# Unable to view images from Firebase in a RecylcerView

Tags: android, firebase

Developing an app for a bookshop. I want to be able to view a list of books with their images beside them. I am able to upload the picture to Firebase Storage and a reference to that picture is in my table.

I am trying to use a RecyclerView, the names come up but the images don't appear. I've been debugging the app and the file name is coming up but I don't know if it is being saved properly in my Add Book Activity.

Here is where I choose a book:

```
  private void chooseFile()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null )
        {

            filePath = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

Then my Glide Part where I want to display the image:

         @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mTitle.setText(titleList.get(position));
            holder.mAuthor.setText(authorList.get(position));

    //        ParseFile image = (ParseFile) bookImageList.get(position).get("image");
    //        String url = image.getUrl();
    //        Glide.with(context)
    //                .load(url)
    //                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
    //                .into(holder.bookImage);

            String image = bookImageList.get(position).toString();

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(image)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.bookImage);

    //        Glide.with(context)
    //                .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bookapplication-725d9.appspot.com/o/images%2F6faf4b68-bf60-416b-b3d8-622cb8e8c63b?alt=media&token=3982bf64-a98c-421e-a133-26da82d03b58")
    //                .fitCenter()
    //                .into(holder.bookImage);

            //Glide.with(context).load(bookImageList.get(position)).asBitmap().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.bookImage);
        }
```

**EDIT** My full Adapter Class:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> titleList;
    ArrayList<String> authorList;
    ArrayList<String> categoryList;
    ArrayList<String> priceList;
    ArrayList<String> quantityList;
    ArrayList<String> bookImageList;

    class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView bookImage;
        TextView mTitle, mAuthor;

        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            bookImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookImage);
            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleSearchItem);
            mAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.authorSearchItem);

        }
    }

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> titleList, ArrayList<String> authorList, ArrayList<String> categoryList, ArrayList<String> priceList, ArrayList<String> quantityList,ArrayList<String> bookImageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.titleList = titleList;
        this.authorList = authorList;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.priceList = priceList;
        this.quantityList = quantityList;
        this.bookImageList = bookImageList;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_list_items, parent, false);
        return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTitle.setText(titleList.get(position));
        holder.mAuthor.setText(authorList.get(position));

//        ParseFile image = (ParseFile) bookImageList.get(position).get("image");
//        String url = image.getUrl();
//        Glide.with(context)
//                .load(url)
//                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
//                .into(holder.bookImage);

        String image = bookImageList.get(position).toString();

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(image)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.bookImage);

//        Glide.with(context)
//                .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bookapplication-725d9.appspot.com/o/images%2F6faf4b68-bf60-416b-b3d8-622cb8e8c63b?alt=media&token=3982bf64-a98c-421e-a133-26da82d03b58")
//                .fitCenter()
//                .into(holder.bookImage);

        //Glide.with(context).load(bookImageList.get(position)).asBitmap().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.bookImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titleList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you upload full code of adapter?

Comment: @kdblue yeah sure, anything in particular?

Comment: #Adapter class ?

Comment: Does it work with .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bookapplication-725d9.appspot.com/o/images%2F6faf4b68-bf60-416b-b3d8-622cb8e8c63b?alt=media&token=3982bf64-a98c-421e-a133-26da82d03b58")?

Comment: I think the problem may be in the `String image = bookImageList.get(position).toString()` probably Glide doesn't recognize it, because it has to be a path or a URL, you need to make sure you get a valid URL

Comment: @kdblue just updated

Comment: @KaranModi yes, all the entries come up with the same picture

Comment: @LieForBananas how do I get a valid url? Path doesn't return it

Comment: had you check your firebase , is it storing your books images?

Comment: @kdblue yes, I have storage set up. I can screenshot some stuff if you want to have a closer look?

Comment: if `image` is a valid url (you can check using debugger or log) try replacing `String image = bookImageList.get(position).toString();` with `Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(bookImageList.get(position).toString())`

Comment: make model class and put  titleList,authorList,categoryList,priceList,quantityList,bookImageList inside that 
 , it will easier to find error !

Comment: @ChloeFinn I haven't used Firebase, but [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) page seems to explain how to do it in "Downloading Images with FirebaseUI", but I think you are familiar with it